# Ошибка ResourceExhaustedError при тренировке нейросети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь натренировать свою первую нейронку.

При попытке ее тренировать - появляется такая ошибка:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM
>   when allocating tensor with shape[502656,128] and type float on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

Почитал, понял, что это из-за того, что мало памяти в видеокарте (GTX 1050 2 gb).

Получается, что мне вообще никак не получится использовать здесь видеокарту?

Может, можно как-то "порциями" выдавать видеокарте dataset?

Код:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

batch_size = 1
num_classes = 3
epochs = 2

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 135, 240

dataset = Dataset()

x_train, y_train = dataset.LoadDataset()

x_train = x_train[0]
y_train = y_train[0]

x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(10000, 135, 240, 1)

input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')

x_train = x_train / 255

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([x_train], [y_train],
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1)

model.save("First.model")

score = model.evaluate([x_train], [y_train], verbose=0)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже часть видеопамяти уже занята (возможно видео драйвером, CUDA, etc.).

Чтобы увидеть объем видеопамяти доступный для Tensorflow, запустите следующую команду:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Вот что показывает Tensorflow для моей GTX 1070 (8GiB RAM) сразу после старта `iPython`:

```
In [6]: sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2019-01-29 19:37:05.630989: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
2019-01-29 19:37:06.219693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7845
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.63GiB
2019-01-29 19:37:06.234201: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-01-29 19:37:08.175263: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-29 19:37:08.189782: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0
2019-01-29 19:37:08.199701: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
2019-01-29 19:37:08.210621: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6391 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2019-01-29 19:37:08.243113: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:307] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
```

Обратите внимание на эту строку:

```
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.63GiB
```